# Print a literal % in a RPM SPEC file?

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

How do you print a literal % symbol in a RPM SPEC file?

I am trying to do something like this in my %post section:

```
echo "%_pkgverify_level none" >/etc/rpm/macros.verify
```

In the /etc/rpm/macros.verify file I only see 'digest none' it doesn't print it literal as '%_pkgverify_level none'.

I don't want the `%` to expand I want it just literal. Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Try doubling it. `echo "%%_pkgverify_level none" >/etc/rpm/macros.verify`

Comment: Thanks that worked great! I had tried everything under the sun, but that. Thanks again!